# How can I disable/grey-out a menu tab dropdown in a jupyterlab extension?

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am building a jupyter lab extension that adds a new tab to the main menu with a dropdown.  I want to set a boolean to determine when certain options in the dropdown are greyed-out/disabled.  I tried adding "disabled":true in the plugin.json file for the command, but that just deletes the tab rather than disable it.  I want it to look something like this:

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kh7c.png)

Comment: Some of the discussions [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/getting-a-strange-error-when-trying-to-add-a-new-menu-item-to-the-main-menu-bar/14349?u=fomightez) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/add-entries-to-the-filebrowser-contextmenu/1651/2?u=fomightez) (that one may be too old now but has details and hopefully it has evolved along that same line) and [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/search?q=menu%20jupyterlab%20extension). Or if you get no pointers here, then posting at the Jupyter Discourse Forum (importantly, with links here to there & there to here) may be a good idea.